# GroupBy(params string[] fields)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

Linq to Object `GroupBy` extension method allows grouping by projection:

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = …
var groups = products.GroupBy(p => new { p.Price, p.Category });
```

Here is the solution to specify field names at runtime in a way like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Product, Product>> groups = 
     products.GroupBy("Price",  "Category");
```

Supports `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is Entity or Anonymous Type, tested with EF6.

Just one class to simplify copy/paste:

```
public static class PropertyGrouping
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, T>> GroupBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params string[] fields) =>
        source.GroupBy(
            typeof(T).IsAnonymous()
                ? source.SelectAnonymous(fields)
                : source.SelectEntity(fields),
            new PropertyComparer<T>(fields));

    class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public PropertyComparer(params string[] properties)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            Properties = properties
                .Select(name => type.GetProperty(name))
                .ToArray();
        }

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties { get; }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y) =>
            Properties.Aggregate(true, (eq, p) => eq && Equals(p.GetValue(x), p.GetValue(y)));

        public int GetHashCode(T obj) =>
            Properties.Aggregate(0, (h, p) => h ^ (p.GetValue(obj)?.GetHashCode() ?? 0));
    }

    static Func<T, T> SelectAnonymous<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string[] fields)
    {
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "x");
        var ctor = itemType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var selector =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(
                Expression.New(ctor,
                    ctor.GetParameters()
                        .Select(p => fields.Contains(p.Name)
                            ? (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, p.Name)
                            : (Expression)Expression.Constant(p.ParameterType.IsValueType
                                ? Activator.CreateInstance(p.ParameterType) : null,
                                p.ParameterType))
                        .ToArray(),
                    itemType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray()),
                itemParam);

        return selector.Compile();
    }

    static Func<T, T> SelectEntity<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string[] fields)
    {
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        var groupType = itemType;
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "x");
        var bindings = from f in fields
                       select Expression.Bind(
                           groupType.GetMember(f).Single(),
                           Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, f));

        var selector = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(groupType), bindings.ToArray());
        return Expression
            .Lambda<Func<T, T>>(selector, itemParam)
            .Compile();
    }

    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<T, T>> GroupBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, params string[] fields) => typeof(T).IsAnonymous()
        ? source.GroupAnonymousBy(fields)
        : source.GroupEntitiesBy(fields);

    static Boolean IsAnonymous(this Type type)
    {
        var hasCompilerGeneratedAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false).Count() > 0;
        var nameContainsAnonymousType = type.FullName.Contains("AnonymousType");
        return hasCompilerGeneratedAttribute && nameContainsAnonymousType;
    }

    static IQueryable<IGrouping<T, T>> GroupAnonymousBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, params string[] fields)
    {
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "x");
        var ctor = itemType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var selector =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(
                Expression.New(ctor,
                    ctor.GetParameters()
                        .Select(p => fields.Contains(p.Name) 
                            ? (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, p.Name) 
                            : (Expression)Expression.Constant(p.ParameterType.IsValueType
                                ? Activator.CreateInstance(p.ParameterType) : null, 
                                p.ParameterType))
                        .ToArray(),
                    itemType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray()),
                itemParam);

        return source.GroupBy(selector);
    }

    static IQueryable<IGrouping<T, T>> GroupEntitiesBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string[] fields)
    {
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                     .Where(m => m.Name == "GroupBy")
                     .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                     .MakeGenericMethod(itemType, itemType.Derive());

        var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, source.Select(fields) });
        return (IQueryable<IGrouping<T, T>>)result;
    }

    static Expression Select<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string[] fields)
    {
        var itemType = typeof(T);
        var groupType = itemType.Derive();
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "x");
        var bindings = from f in fields
                       select Expression.Bind(
                           groupType.GetMember(f).Single(),
                           Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, f));

        var selector = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(groupType), bindings.ToArray());
        return Expression.Lambda(selector, itemParam);
    }

    static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type> GroupTypes { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type>();

    static Type Derive(this Type baseType) => GroupTypes.GetOrAdd(baseType, t =>
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName($"TempAssm_{Guid.NewGuid():N}");
        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("core");
        var groupTypeName = $"{baseType}_{Guid.NewGuid():N}";
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(groupTypeName);
        var notMappedCtor = typeof(NotMappedAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        var notMappedBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(notMappedCtor, new object[0]);
        typeBuilder.SetParent(baseType);
        typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(notMappedBuilder);
        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the coolest real-world example of how useful expressions are ;-)

Comment: Agree with @t3chb0t. Really nice code!

Comment: :O :O this is magical! Question: Do you know how I can edit this code so it supports sub-types? for example within an `OrderModel` there is a `Contact`, and I want to filter on `ContactId` of `Contact`? So that I can insert `Contact.ContactId` as property field? Would be amazing! Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616916/build-relational-grouping-expression-tree-c-sharp

Comment: Another question: Is it true that the `T` models that are consuming this, are all implementing `IEquatable` or have overriden `GetHashCode` and/or `Equals`? Because without it, it seems to not group them correctly. `Equals` or `GetHasCode` within `PropertComparer<T>` seems not to be called.

Comment: After with a fair amount of trial getting this to work with .net core I get the following error. `Client side GroupBy is not supported.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few things I noticed:

---

> ```
> public PropertyComparer(params string[] properties)
> {
>   var type = typeof(T);
>   Properties = properties
>       .Select(name => type.GetProperty(name))
>       .ToArray();
> }
> ```

There is no need for the lambda and it could be written as:

```
    Properties = properties
        .Select(type.GetProperty)
        .ToArray();
```

but for this to be clear the name `properties` should be changed to `propertyNames`.

---

> ```
> public bool Equals(T x, T y) =>
>           Properties.Aggregate(true, (eq, p) => eq && Equals(p.GetValue(x), p.GetValue(y)));
> ```

This `Aggregate` could simplified with `All` which would stop checking other properties if the result of `Equals` would be `false` for any of them:

```
public bool Equals(T x, T y) => Properties.All(p => Equals(p.GetValue(x), p.GetValue(y)))
```

---

> ```
> var selector =
>   Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(
>       Expression.New(ctor,
>           ctor.GetParameters()
>               .Select(p => fields.Contains(p.Name)
>                   ? (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, p.Name)
>                   : (Expression)Expression.Constant(p.ParameterType.IsValueType
>                       ? Activator.CreateInstance(p.ParameterType) : null,
>                       p.ParameterType))
>               .ToArray(),
>           itemType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray()),
>       itemParam);
> ```

Unless I didn't find the difference this exact same block of code seems to occur twice in your code, both in the `SelectAnonymous` and the `GroupAnonymousBy`.

---

The method `GroupEntitiesBy` uses a magic number `2` in this line

> ```
> .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
> ```

I guess you are looking here for a `GroupBy` with two parameters.

> ```
> var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
>            .Where(m => m.Name == "GroupBy")
>            .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
>            .MakeGenericMethod(itemType, itemType.Derive());
> ```

It'd be safer to serch for parameters by type I think rather then relying on the count. If for whatever reason they add another `GroupBy` overload with two parameters in future it could break. The same goes for `Single`. Also the string `"GroupBy"` could be replaced with `nameof(Queryable.GroupBy)`.

---

> ```
> var notMappedCtor = typeof(NotMappedAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
> ```

This line in the `Derive` method could use `Type.EmptyTypes` in place of the empty array.

I also don't like the huge lambda here `GroupTypes.GetOrAdd(baseType, t =>`. It would make more sense to make it a testable helper method in another class than immediately saving and *hiding* the result in a dictionary.

---

Other than these few nitpicks I find this an amazingly clean and useful piece of code that *demonstrates* how practical expression-trees and dynamic code generation could be and I have to study it more ;-)